# Why cons give a different value based on position of S-expression

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

So if i were to write a function add1 like so

```
(define add1 (lambda (n)
                (cons n (quote()) )))

(add1 '(()))
```

my answer is - `'((()))`

an empty list added inside another empty list, not the answer i want

however if i change the function to

```
(define add1 (lambda (n)
                (cons  (quote()) n )))
```

just writing quote() first i get

```
 '(() ())
```

which is what i want, why in the first case the cons added a list inside a list and in second case beside a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(cons 42 (cons 69 (cons 613 '())))` is `(list 42 69 613)`

[image]

In here we use Intermediate Student languages to let us easily check result.

```
#lang htdp/isl
```

`(quote ())` is `'()` and `'(())` is `(cons '() '())`.

```
#lang htdp/isl
; Intermediate Student languages

(equal? (quote ()) '())
(equal? '(()) (cons '() '()))
```

So we rewrite your function

```
#lang htdp/isl
; Intermediate Student languages

(define (f1 x)
  (cons x '()))

(define (f2 x)
  (cons  '() x))

(define a (cons '() '()))
```

We know`a` = `(cons '() '())` = `(list '())`.

`(f1 a)` will do `(cons a '())` will output `(list (list '()))`.

Think like this you input `(cons "abc" '())` of course you will get `(list "abc")`. So `(cons a '())` will get `(list a)`.

`(cons '() '())` is `(list '())` so when you run `(f2 a)`. Just like `(cons 1 (list 2))` will get `(list 1 2)`. It just do `(cons '() (list '())` so you will get `(list '() '())`.

---

Imagine `(list 1 2)` and `(list 3 4)` and `(cons (list 1 2) (list 3 4))`

In internet have some people explain `list` like this. It not really make sense.

[image]
[image]

The better method is draw `list` like binary tree. Every right branch have to be a `list`.

[image]
[image]